# How to get a list of all storage accounts in Azure? (C#)

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage, azure-functions

I couldn't find anything about how to get all `storage accounts`, I know it is possible get all `blob containers` and `queues`, so Is it possible to get all `storage accounts` by Azure-Functions?

Or is it possible to generate a unique `SAS Token` for access all `storage Accounts`, so I can use on `StorageCredentials(string sasToken)` ?

Comment: You can also list storage accounts by using PowerShell:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-powershell-guide-full#list-the-storage-accounts-in-the-subscription

Comment: @VikranthS I know is is possible by PowerShell, but I want to do this on C#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

another option for getting a list of all storage accounts under the subscription is to use the REST API, see [Storage Accounts - List.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storagerp/storageaccounts/list)

Note, that the *Bearer token* is required.

Comment: I do recommend to solve an authorization Bearer token (registering app in the AAD, etc.). Once you have it, you can get any resource from the ARM using the REST API calls. (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.identitymodel.clients.activedirectory.authenticationcontext?view=azure-dotnet   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-integrating-applications)

Comment: I used AzureServiceTokenProvider for the token, the problem was multiple subscriptions so I just need to pass tenatId to get the correct token.

Answer (score 4):

You could use `Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent` to list all the storage account in your subscription.

Refer to the following code:

```
var credentials = SdkContext.AzureCredentialsFactory.FromFile(@"D:\azurecred.txt"); 
var azure = Azure       
    .Configure()
    .WithLogLevel(HttpLoggingDelegatingHandler.Level.Basic)
    .Authenticate(credentials)
    .WithDefaultSubscription();
var account = azure.StorageAccounts.List();
```

You need to set subscription,client,key,tenantId in your credentials file.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I dont  have high privileges on the azure account to generate client and key (Azure Active Directory)

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to get all storage accounts using the `StorageManagementClient` (you have to install the `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Storage` NuGet package).

After you set your authentication and subscription you can call the `List()` method on the `StorageAccounts` property. e. g. :

```
new StorageManagementClient().StorageAccounts.List()
```

> The List Storage Accounts operation lists the storage accounts that
>   are available in the specified subscription.

[Source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/ee460787.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the answer but i could use this api link, seems like deprecated